# Bash Simulate User input for terminal gui program

Tags: linux, bash, input, raspberry-pi

I have been trying to automate the setup process for pi hole on a raspberry pi. I am relatively new to bash and am unable to figure out how to automate the setup process once the terminal gui for the program begins.

[image: terminal gui opened by pihole -r]

this is what I have so far

```
#!/bin/bash

pihole -r

echo "waited"

$SHELL
```

So I reiterate back to my question, how do I automate the task of choosing and entering the option in the terminal gui of the pihole program? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's already a script that should be able to do it for you ("***Pi-hole Automated Install***")

To execute it you'd do:

```
curl -L install.pi-hole.net | bash
```

> unfortunately it's too big to post here, so you'll want to grab it
>   here:

↳ [Github : Pi-hole Automated Install](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pi-hole/pi-hole/master/automated%20install/basic-install.sh)